# Cómo agregar un ‘placeholder’ en un JTextField

Tags: java, java-swing

Quisiera tener una caja de texto (`jTextField`) y que al arrancar el formulario en **JAVA SWING** en esa caja de texto aparezca un *texto "informativo"* de lo que hay que rellenar en ese campo. Y que al hacer click o al insertar el primer caracter ese texto informativo desaparezca.
Probé con `setToolTipText` pero lo que hace es al pasar el ratón encima del `jTextField` informa, no lo añade a la caja de Texto.

Probe con `nombre.setText("Informativo");`
pero de esa forma tiene el valor por defecto éste, y al escribir lo suma al que tenía. No me vale.

Comment: pero donde lo declaramos, o instanciamos, puedes explicarnos, o subiruna muestra de codigo? gracias.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lo que tú quieres es una especie de [*placeholder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder). Una solución es utilizar la clase [`TextPrompt`](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) de Rob Camick, cuyo uso es muy simple. Ejemplo:

❍ *Código:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    TextPrompt placeholder = new TextPrompt("Apellido Paterno", textField);
    placeholder.changeAlpha(0.75f);
    placeholder.changeStyle(Font.ITALIC);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textField);
}
```

❍ *Salida:*

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: Mejor explicado imposible, eso es... lo que en HTML sería un placeholder, muy bien y gracias.

Comment: Estoy venga a buscar algún JAR o la librería necesaria (import java...) para poder utilizar la clase TextPrompt pero no la encuentro. ¿Cuál es?

Comment: @omaza1990 Lo único que necesitas es [este](http://www.camick.com/java/source/TextPrompt.java) archivo. Si lo colocas en el mismo paquete de tu formulario, no necesitas agregar el `import`.

Comment: Toda la información perfecta. +1

Comment: pero si limpio campo como hago para que me salga enseguida nuevamente!!? por que cuando limpio campo no me aparece el placeholder a menos que le haga click dentro del jtextfield y luego afuera

Answer (score 2):

1. Descarga el plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/70043/placeholder
2. import com.placeholder.PlaceHolder;
3. En..   initComponents();

   ```
   PlaceHolder holder = new PlaceHolder(tuCampoDeText, "lo que quieras que se muestre");
   ```