# Como agregar un placeholder en un JPasswordField

Tags: java, java-swing

Como el título de mi pregunta indica, estoy intentando añadir un placeholder en un JPasswordField, sin embargo podría decirse que lo he logrado a medias.

Lo que he hecho hasta ahora es utilizar el siguiente código (el cual adapté de una respuesta que encontré en SO):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextFieldUI;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class TextFieldWithPromptUI extends BasicTextFieldUI implements FocusListener
{
  private final String hint;
  private final boolean hideOnFocus;
  private final Color color;
  private final Font font;

  public TextFieldWithPromptUI(String hint, boolean hideOnFocus, Font font, Color color)
  {
    this.hint = hint;
    this.hideOnFocus = hideOnFocus;
    this.font = font;
    this.color = color;
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintSafely(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintSafely(g);
    JTextComponent comp = getComponent();    
    if (comp.getText().length() == 0 && (!hideOnFocus || !comp.isFocusOwner()))
    {
      g.setColor(color);
      g.setFont(font);
      int padding = (comp.getHeight() - comp.getFont().getSize()) / 2;
      g.drawString(hint, 2, comp.getHeight() - padding - 1);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
  {
    if (hideOnFocus)
    {
      getComponent().repaint();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
  {
    if (hideOnFocus)
    {
      getComponent().repaint();
    }
  }  
}
```

Este código permite añadir un placeholder satisfactoriamente al JPasswordField, pero el problema es que se muestran los caracteres que se escriben en la caja de texto, esto es, ya no salen los astericos ('`*`') que ocultan dichos caracteres.

Adjunto una imagen para que se aprecie lo que sucede:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como puedo modificar la clase anterior para adaptarla a un JPasswordField. Muchas gracias de antemano por sus respuestas y/o comentarios.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42187/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-un-placeholder-en-un-jtextfield revisa eso porfavor

Comment: @x-rw gracias, pero ya revisé esa pregunta. Lo que pasa es que estoy evitando utilizar clases que no vienen por defecto en Swing.

Comment: te respondi puedes probarlo.

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar con el siguiente codigo

```
            PlaceholderTextField ph = new PlaceholderTextField("hola soy placeholder");
            ph.setColumns(100);
            Font f = ph.getFont();
            ph.setFont(new Font(f.getName(), f.getStyle(), 30));
```

Comment: Una consulta, ¿cómo añadiría el código anterior a la clase que estoy utilizando (`TextFieldWithPromptUI`)? o es que acaso tengo que invocarlo directamente en el `main`?

Comment: @Xam lo añades al jpasswordfield que dices